# iPhone 4s no display constant charging sound

Tags: display, iphone, screen

There is no display on my iPhone 4s, but whenever I hook it up to my charger, it will play the charging sound every 7 seconds. Maybe something is loose in the phone? I am thinking there is something up with the LCD screen thing, I can see in the sim card slot a pink-ish thing, and some bent metal of some sort. Please help. Don't know what to do.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a different charging cable? 
Try holding the home and power buttons together to do a hard reset and see if that reboots the iPhone. 
Does iTunes recognize the device when it's connected to your computer?
Are you able to fully remove the SIM card from the device?